# Can I define command-line commands for VsVim?

Tags: visual-studio, vim, vsvim

Is it possible to define my own custom command-line commands in VsVim like it can be done in Vim and [described here](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_40.html#40.2)?

I tried adding different variations of the following lines to my .vsvimrc file, without success.

```
command clean :vsc CodeMaid.CleanupCode<cr>
:command clean :vsc CodeMaid.CleanupCode<cr>
command clean execute ":vsc CodeMaid.CleanupCode<cr>"
```

Although

```
nmap :clean :vsc CodeMaid.CleanupCode<cr>
```

seems to work, it is not what I was really looking for.

Comment: As an aside, Vim user commands need to start with a capital letter, it's maybe mentioned maybe 9 lines down in the documentation you link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the source, from what I can tell it does not have support for user-defined commands via the `:command` command.
https://github.com/jaredpar/VsVim/blob/master/Src/VimCore/Interpreter_Parser.fs#L121

You can ask the author if he plans to add support for it, the best place for that is probably the Q&A section of the plugin's page:
https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/59ca71b3-a4a3-46ca-8fe1-0e90e3f79329/view/Discussions

Looking at the structure of his command parser briefly, it seems like it might be a lot of work to add support for custom commands, but it can't hurt to ask.